# FSRM Auto apply template not applying to exisiting folders

Tags: windows-server-2016, file-server, quota

I have set up an auto-apply template using FSRM to a path with a number of existing subfolders but when I apply it, the exisiting folders are not getting a quota created for them.

- There are 174 sub-folders, combined size is ~6.5GB, 13k files.
- New sub-folders created after the quota get a quota applied to them, likewise with a folder that is renamed
- There are no errors in the event viewer that appear to link to it
- I have tried deleting and re-creating the quota
- When a new parent folder & sub-folders are created the same directory, the auto-apply works as intended
- Permissions for the parent folder are the same as a newly created folder
- If I copy the parent folder and all contents to a new folder, it applies the auto-quota
- Server version is Windows Server 2016 Standard running on Hyper-V with CU 2022-04 installed

I can just script a solution to do them individually and get around the problem but I'd like to try and figure out why this isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So writing out the question basically led me to the answer. I made one edit to the question adding

> If I copy the parent folder and all contents to a new folder, it
> applies the auto-quota

I did this quickly with Powershell and got a few long path name errors but ignored them as they don't affect quotas. So I decided to fix them while I was there and nestled in them was this error:

[image: Powershell error]

Explorer error when trying to access:

[image: The handle is invalid error]

Turns out our username format ended up creating a folder that started with `CON.` [which isn't allowed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

**Answer:** You can't have any illegal filenames in a folder you're trying to apply an auto-quota to otherwise it will not apply the quotas to *any* of the sub-folders